# Set version number in child's style.css file

Tags: css

I need help with a small issue.

I want the child theme style.css file to be loaded from scratch since I'm doing heavy graphic modification and no all the changes are properly loaded.

I know this can be done using the style.css?ver=XXXX.

I see that my website is now loading the version 5.3 that I imagine being the wordpress version running on the website atm.

What files (where and how) do I need to change to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can define the version when enqueuing the file :

```
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", function () {

    wp_enqueue_style(
          "child-style"
        , get_stylesheet_uri() // = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/style.css"
        , ["parent-style"]
        , wp_get_theme()->version // use the child theme version
    );


});
```

Comment: Is this supposed to go in the function.php file? In the main or child theme folder?

Comment: in `functions.php` of the child theme

Comment: So I'll paste the code there and I'll see. Thank you!

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't working. I put the exact same code int the child theme function.php file, but it's still loading the old version of the style.css

Comment: look the source in the browser to be sure to have `style.css?ver=....`